# How to disable q/arc endpoints from a quarkus webapp?

Tags: quarkus

I have a quarkus webapp, and I am using the health extension, namely 'quarkus-smallrye-health'. I accidentally hit a page that does not exist and it lists a list of all the endpoints that are currently exposed.

It exposes CDI related extensions which I don't want. How can I disable it? I am unable to find anything in the public documentation. Kindly help.

[image]

Comment: This page only shows up in DevMode, it does **not** show up when running the production application.

Comment: @geoand I ran the app after setting the env variable QUARKUS_PROFILE=prod and still see this

Comment: profile might be overridden by other configuration. How do you run your app ?

Comment: the app runs in the right profile. I know this since I see properties picked up from application-<profile>.properties file @jacouille

Comment: based on what you show, it does not seem to be the case. That's why I asked how you run it, because profile could be overriden in a few ways other than properties.
Try running with -Dquarkus.profile=prod, and devUI should be gone

Comment: Found the issue. Quakus will behave differently when run with java -jar and when run from the IDE / mvn quarkus:dev -D quarkus.profile=profile. When running from a docker container which runs the uber jar, the arc related endpoints are not there anymore.